# What events will add an entry to Chrome's history? I am getting inconsistent results

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, iframe, browser-history

In my case a user clicks a link with an href of "#foobar-popup". I use that onclick event to build an iframe, inject it into the dom, and display it. I don't do any form of preventing the default behavior so the hash is appended to the browser's address. It works great. I then bind the "hashchange" event to the window. When $(window).on('hashchange', ...) is triggered I look at the current hash. If it does not start with "#foobar-" (meaning the hash is now gone and the browser stepped back in history) I call a function to remove the iframe from the dom. This works the majority of the time. However, every once in a while when I click "Back" expecting the iframe to go away it does nothing. I setup an alert on the hashchange event to tell me what the new hash is. It doesn't ever get triggered even though the hash DID in fact change. I thought maybe it is confusing the two different windows (parent window and newly injected iframe) but it isn't.

In the iframe I do not do any navigating so it *shouldn't be* adding any entries to the history.

By the way, I don't like this solution but given the current state of the app it is the best decision to get from point a to point b with the least amount of adding bulk to the project.

I'm using jquery-1.8.3. I've read about some history plugins but they seem like a bit of overkill for this.

Here is the code listening for hashchange:

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
    if (!(location.hash.match("^#foobar-id"))) {
        if ($("#popup-background").length || $("#popup-frame").length) {
            $("#popup-background, #popup-frame").remove();
        }
    }
 });
```

EDIT: More info... I am adding an iframe and removing an iframe to the dom. I've found that when you remove an iframe it messes up the browser history but I can't get it to consistently happen. I figure if you delete the iframe from dom it looses a chunk of the overall history, if that is even a thing..?

Comment: I'm starting to think that the hashchange event is becoming unbound somehow.

Comment: Are you expecting your javascript to run when you click the 'Previous' button? Chrome seems to keep the last known state of its history pages. If you go back to that page, chrome will display that state, it will not process the page again (and by extension, will not run any javascript). Unless forced, of course.
Logically, if Chrome does not interpret a #hashed URL as a different page, it's quite possible the browser is only saving the last known state of that page, i.e. with the iframe included.

Comment: @Flater , Ideally I'd like the function to be called any time the browser history goes back a step or -1. So when a user clicks the back button, performs a gesture for go back, or even if i create a button that has onclick of "history.go(-1);". All of the events mentioned will remove the hash that was previously added.

Comment: You can put an extra back button on there, but you can't force users to use it. The company I work at makes it a habit of making the error page so that you cannot use the browser's back button (it keeps loading the same error page, no matter how long you click.) But I'm not sure how this is implemented.